# Octave error: some elements in list of return values are undefined

Tags: arrays, matrix, octave

I'm Building a Matrix With a Generator, I'm try to get value column according with the value in other `list_ones`

```
list_ones=[4,3,2,1]
```

I want my output to be:

```
   0   0   0   1
   0   0   1   0
   0   1   0   0
   1   0   0   0
```

the code do correctly but it has this wrong: some elements in list of return values are undefined

```
function y=matrixGenerator(list_ones, size)
  List1=[];
  Linha=[];
  nl = size;
  nc = size;
  for i = 1:nl
    elem=list_ones(i);       
    for j = 1:nc      
      if (elem==j)
         M(i,j) = 1;
      else
         M(i,j) = 0;
      endif      
    end
  end
  M
endfunction
```

Comment: What elements are undefined? You’ve shown your expected output, please show also your actual output.

Comment: Oh, I see. You declare the function with `function y=matrixGenerator(...)`, then you must use variable `y` as the output. Since you create matrix `M` as output, declare your function with `function M=matrixGenerator(...)`

Comment: @CrisLuengo if I may reboot our 'matlab tag' discussion from elsewhere, this is an excellent example where I think removing the tag was inappropriate. There is a large number of compatible matlab duplicates on one-hot encoding. It would have been far more appropriate for this question to have been closed as duplicate to one of them instead. I would highly question that the mere use of `endfunction` instead of `end` at the end of this code signifies that the user would specifically require a non-matlab-compatible solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result in two way:

You can use your `matrixGenerator` method:

```
function y = matrixGenerator(list_ones)
sz = length(list_ones);
y = zeros(sz, sz);
for i=1:sz
    idx = list_ones(i);
    y(i, idx) = 1;
end
disp(y)
end
```

Outptut:

```
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0
     1     0     0     0
```

or, you can use `built-in` function:

```
clear; clc

A = flip(eye(4));

disp(A)
```

Output:

```
0     0     0     1
0     0     1     0
0     1     0     0
1     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `sub2ind` in the function `matrixGenerator`

```
function y = matrixGenerator(list_ones)
  sz = length(list_ones)*ones(1,2);
  y = zeros(sz);
  y(sub2ind(sz,1:length(list_ones),list_ones)) = 1;
endfunction
```

such that

```
>> matrixGenerator(list_ones)
ans =

   0   0   0   1
   0   0   1   0
   0   1   0   0
   1   0   0   0
```